# How to check the photo is selected when try to upload a photo

Tags: php, codeigniter

i make a form to upload a text and a photo(* where optional to upload photo).

this my code in view:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"/>
```

**THE QUESTION IS:
how i can check the user upload/browse/select a photo/file or not??**

my code like on controller like this:

```
$data['name'] = $this->input->post('firstname',TRUE);
$data['photo'] = $this->input->post('userfile',TRUE);
if(!isset($data['photo'])){
echo "you not select a photo/file" ;
}else{
echo "you select a photo/file";
}
```

But, i found the error…
if i not select a photo , the output is “you select a photo/file”;

and if i select a photo , the output is “you select a photo/file”;

i think the error is

1. $data[‘photo’] = $this->input->post(‘userfile’,TRUE);
2. if(!isset($data[‘photo’]))

please give me a solution.. thanks,,,

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']));
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. that's not work..

i try using

    if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){
    } 

and it works... thank you very much,,,,

Comment: @ZulkifliSaid no problem. you might want to select an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
if ( $_FILES['userfile']['error'] === 0 ) { }
```

that will be true if the user added a file and it all worked ok from the form's point of view. also don't forget to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag

Comment: thanks... it works...

i try using

   `code` if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name'])){
    } `code`

and it works... thank you very much,,,,

Comment: you should really check the error rathe than the name as it might have a name but still not have uploaded correctly

Comment: sip... thanks.. now i using if ( $_FILES['userfile']['error'] === 0 ) { }